# Proper way to share your script in a small network

Tags: python, dependencies

I am a newbie at Python and I am starting my first tests. So, I have created the below script which has the following structure :

[image]

My question is, lets say that now I want to make this available for other users. the simplest way I can think of, is to create a folder in **/bin/my_python_app** and copy everything there.

The thing is, this looks a little brute.

What is the right way to do this?

Is there a way in which I can bundle all the script dependencies in one file and have that as the "binary" of my app so other people can run it?

I dont want people doing any other thing that simply run my app, without requiring them to install it or add any other kind of extra packages to their system.

Comment: you can cx_freeze to create a "binary" out of your python  ... you could also make a debian file ... keep in mind the binary will only work for the system that it is built for (see also: https://ptmccarthy.github.io/2016/01/22/python-cx-freeze/ )

Comment: @JoranBeasley well I accidentally left a comment for you as an answer. :( Thanks buddy